# How to use instanceof operator of java here?

Tags: java, operator-keyword, instanceof

I'm solving this problem in Hackerrank. How can i use `instanceof` operator in Java to successfully compile the code?

**Link :** https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/java-iterator

**The incomplete code :**

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main
{
static Iterator func(ArrayList mylist)
{
  Iterator it=mylist.iterator();
  while(it.hasNext())
  {
     Object element = it.next();
     if(~~Complete this line~~)//Hints: use instanceof operator
        break;
  }
  return it;

}

public static void main(String []argh)
{
  ArrayList mylist = new ArrayList();
  Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
  int n=sc.nextInt();
  int m=sc.nextInt();
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
     mylist.add(sc.nextInt());
  }
  mylist.add("###");
  for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
  {
     mylist.add(sc.next());
  }


  Iterator it=func(mylist);
  while(it.hasNext())
  {
     Object element = it.next();
     System.out.println((String)element);
  }

 }
}
```

Even though i got it done by using `if(element == "###")`, please guide me on how to use `instanceof` operator at that place.

**Edit : That thread couldn't provide answers as to how to use that instanceof operator to check for the instance of a special character group like "###" in a ArrayList. Please help me understand. Sorry if I'm violating any rule here.**

Comment: Sorry, But i had gone through that thread earlier and couldn't understand how to use instanceof operator in my problem. Can you please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is adding `Integer` instances followed by `String` instances to the same `ArrayList`.

Though you didn't say so, it seems the goal of `func` is to return an `Iterator` that points to the first `String` element following the "###" element. Therefore `func` should iterate over the elements of the `ArrayList` until it encounters a `String` instance, which would be the "###" `String`.

```
static Iterator func(ArrayList mylist)
{
  Iterator it=mylist.iterator();
  while(it.hasNext())
  {
     Object element = it.next();
     if(element instanceof String)
        break;
  }
  return it;

}
```

Comment: Bingo! That was spot on! I can't believe i overlooked that detail there! Thanks for answering! :)

Answer (score 1):

Ex of instanceof operator--
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Vector;

public class VecReplace {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Vector vector=new Vector();

        vector.add(0, 10);
        vector.add(1, "xyz");
        vector.add(2, 30);
        vector.add(3, 40);
        System.out.println(vector);

        vector.set(3, "abc");
        System.out.println(vector);

        Enumeration e=vector.elements();
        while(e.hasMoreElements())
        {
            Object o=e.nextElement();
            if(o instanceof Integer)
            {
                Integer i=(Integer) o;

                System.out.println(i);
            }

        }


}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```
if(element instanceof String){
```

.......
}
This should give you the expected output.